# How can I use String.Split with a String delimiter?

Tags: c#, split

I have  string like so:

"ABCDEF--Split--GHIKLMO--Split--PQRSTUVWXYZ"

what I am trying to do is split this string with --Split-- being the delimiter, I have obviously tried the following:

```
var array = item.split('--Split--');
```

but I get this error:

`Too many characters in character literal`

Is there away to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your above code is that you are trying to pass in a string as a char instead of using the correct overload:

```
item.Split(new []{"--Split--"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the string.Split that uses CHAR as parameter. See that single quote are used to create char type in C#.
You have to use the overload that receives an string array as parameter.

```
  item.split(new string[]{"--Split--"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The first parameter is an array of strings that you want to split.
The second parameter, the StringSplitOptions has two possible values:

- None (will split also empty values), the example below will give you an string array with three elements. The first will be "This is an string test", second wil lbe "I will split by ", and third will be "":

  var test = "This is an string test, I will split by ,";
  var splittedStrings = test.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.None);
- RemoveEmptyEntries, this will remove the empty entries of splitted string. If you take the example above using the RemoveEmptyEntries you will have an array with only two values: "This is an string test" and "I will split by ". The empty string at final will be cutted of.